# update a table row based on another row in the same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I created a temp table from my sql server database something like shown below. The temp table has columns Title & Descripton and a few other columns :

```
Title               Description          ABC    Ford    Toyota
Ford Car           This is a Car           A  
Car                This is a Toyota car    B
Toyota Truck       This is a truck         C 
Car                This is a ford car      D
```

I need to create an output such that if the title or description has a word "Ford" or "Toyota" in it . I need a "Yes" in that place. I need the result to look something like below :

*

```
Title             Description           ABC      Ford   Toyota
Ford Car         This is a Car          A        Yes    No
Car              This is a Toyota car   B         No    Yes
Toyota Truck     This is a truck        C         No    Yes
Car              This is a ford car     D        Yes    No
car              ford toyota            E        Yes    Yes
```

*

Could you please let me know how this will work ? Any pointers ? I am kind of stuck here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE tbl
    SET Ford = CASE WHEN Title LIKE '%Ford%' OR Description LIKE '%Ford' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END,
        Toyota = CASE WHEN Title LIKE '%Toyota%' OR Description LIKE '%Toyota' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
```

Comment: darn.. got beaten to it :(

Answer (score 0):

You can update a table from itself, my query below provides the example you have described:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
Title NVARCHAR(20) NULL,
Description NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
ABC NVARCHAR(1) NULL,
Ford NVARCHAR(3) NULL,
Toyota NVARCHAR(3) NULL)

INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES
('Ford Car','This is a Car','A',NULL,NULL),  
('Car','This is a Toyota car','B',NULL,NULL), 
('Toyota Truck','This is a truck','C' ,NULL,NULL), 
('Car','This is a ford car','D' ,NULL,NULL)    

UPDATE #Temp
SET Ford = IIF(#Temp.Title LIKE '%Ford%' OR #Temp.Description LIKE '%Ford%','Yes','No')
   ,Toyota = IIF(#Temp.Title LIKE '%Toyota%' OR #Temp.Description LIKE '%Toyota%','Yes','No')
```